# Is there any way to send data from Java step definition class to feature file in Cucumber framework?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

If it is possible to send data from java step definition class to Feature file, It will be useful for me.

Kindly help in this.

Comment: Nope. Can u clarify the requirement?

Comment: After running the cucumber scenario, I will get output test data. My boss wants that data to be populated in Scenario Title. So that The titile will be shown for as a scenario in Allure report.

Comment: No idea how allure report works but Cucumber reads the feature file only before the scenario is run. So ur approach will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to have support for step returning value. As far as i know gherkin with cucumber doesn't support it. However [Gherkin with QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) supports step with return value and facilitates a way to use it inside bdd or in code. For example:

```
@Given("doing some actions")
public Object myStepReturningValue() {
   //do the needful
   return object;
}
```

In BDD:

```
Given doing some actions
And store into 'action.result'
...
Then using '${action.result}' do something
```

You can use any of the supported [BDD syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) including Gherkin which supported by cucumber.